# Windows 10 white lock screen

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a domain joined Windows 10 computer that when I lock the computer, instead of showing the typical "Press ctrl-ult-del to login", it simply shows a solid white screen.

Also, this solid white screen will not shut off after being inactive, it just stays like that all night.

Not really sure where to go with this. I've updated all my drivers, I've done a system file check (using sfc /scannow), windows is fully updated.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A domain? Is this a big enterprise domain? Or a home server domain?

Comment: @CharlieRB it's a home server domain.

Comment: This almost sounds like the fancy lock screen background thing. Does it happen to all users? UWP packages have a ... habit ... of failing in weird ways.